# Python (1040, 'Too many connections')

Tags: python, mysql, linux, mysql-python

im newbie in Python. 
I have Item table with 3 attributes ( name, price, image) 
I want to get html from link and save to table. So i do that

```
from books.models import Book, Author, Publisher, Item
import urllib
import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb as mdb

def updateItems(request): 
    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'anhnt', '12', 'db_django');
    cur = con.cursor()
    link = "http://pandagift.vn/i263/price1/qua-tang-doc-dao.htm"
    request = urllib.urlopen(link)
    output1 = open('web.txt', 'wb')
    html = ""
    html = request.read()
    output1.write(html)
    output1.close()
    beautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    list_item = beautifulSoup.findAll("div", {"class":"Item_ProcNews"})
    if list_item:
    for item in list_item :
        #lay anh san pham
        image = item.findAll("img")[0]      
        st = str(image)
        beginindex = st.find('src') + 5
            endindex = st.find('jpg') + 3
        if(endindex == 2):
                endindex = st.find('png') + 3
            if(endindex == 2):
            endindex = st.find('jpeg') + 4
            if(endindex == 3):
                endindex = st.find('gif') + 3
            if(endindex == 2):
                        endindex = st.find('bmp') + 3
                if(endindex == 2):
                        endindex = st.find('JPG') + 3
        itemimage = str(image)[beginindex:endindex].encode('utf-8')
        #lay ten san pham
            name = item.findAll("span", {"class":"item-name"})[0]
        temp = name.findAll("a")[0]
        #itemname = temp.get('alt').encode('utf-8')
        itemname = temp.string.encode('utf-8')
            #lay gia san pham
            price = item.findAll("span", {"class":"price"})[0]
        #temp1 = str(price)
        #beginindex1 = temp1.find('price') + 7
            #endindex1 = temp1.find('/span') -1
        #itemprice = str(temp1)[beginindex1:endindex1]
        itemprice = str(price.string)
        #luu vao csdl
        query = "INSERT INTO books_item(name, price, image) VALUES('"+itemname+"', '"+itemprice+"', '"+itemimage+"')"
        cur.execute(query)
        #print query
    else:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO books_item(name, price) VALUES('Hat', '10000vnd')")
    updateItems(request)
```

Its return

```
  Exception Type:   OperationalError
  Exception Value:  (1040, 'Too many connections')
```

Please tell me why its happen and can i do fix it. Thanks many :)

Comment: Please post the full error traceback you are getting. Also, why do you call `updateItems` from `updateItems`? The problem, I'm pretty sure is that you are not closing the database cursor and connection properly.

Comment: Thanks. That's detail error.
OperationalError at /updateItems/

(1040, 'Too many connections')

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/updateItems/
Django Version:  1.6.4
Exception Type:  OperationalError
Exception Value:  

(1040, 'Too many connections')

Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__, line 193
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
---------------- 
I call updateItems because i want updateItems is execute.

Comment: Close your connections when you are done with them.  You have run out of file descriptors.  It's that simple.

Comment: I learn from page www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html.
And in my project
- I have a action in showBooks.html in 'templates' document, call updateItems: 
<form action="/updateItems/" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Update Item">
</form>
- In urls.py file, i set path to it 
url (r'^updateItems/$', views.updateItems)
- In /books/views.py, i have def updateItems that you see.
Ah, i change like that, but it does not still work
<code> else:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO books_item(name, price) VALUES('Hat', '10000vnd')")
    con.close()
    updateItems(request)</code>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/too-many-connections.html

> If you get a Too many connections error when you try to connect to the mysqld server, this means that all available connections are in use by other clients.
>
> The number of connections permitted is controlled by the max_connections system variable. Its default value is 100. If you need to support more connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.

This means that you have opened more connections to the database than permitted by the server without closing them. I never see calls to `close` the connection `con` in your code.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem by increasing the maximum number of connections allowed by MySQL in my django app settings.py file. More information in
[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

```
DATABASES = { 
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
           "init_command": "SET GLOBAL max_connections = 100000", #<-- The fix
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A band-aid... a working one, but a band-aid. Really if you're using too many connections you should figure out why, rather than setting it to some super-high number.

Answer (score 2):

you need: `cur.close()` and `con.close()`.

Every connection should be closed after use it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). And also emphasize your code like this `cur.close()`

Answer (score 1):

My situation is not exactly related to OP, but first result on google for my problem, so...

I was getting the `too many connections` error in django as well. I have two servers deployed on AWS, one EC2 t2.micro (web server) and one RDS t2.micro (mysql database). The web server is running debian, with apt-get installs for apache2 (2.4.10-10+deb8u3), python (2.7.9), and django (1.7.7-1+deb8u3). I'm using django just for the ORM and website is hosted on apache using mod_wsgi.

mysql:

```
mysql> show variables like "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 66    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.23                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.23-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I had to tune down some settings in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` to fix the too many connections error. These four settings were previously not in the config file (default values):

```
ServerLimit 2
MaxRequestWorkers 10
ThreadsPerChild 5

WSGIDaemonProcess aaa threads=6

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ....
```

mysql processlist (`SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE user='www-user'`) now stays around 21.